# How to i establish connection between an Android app and a dekstop application with real-time data sharing

Tags: python, android, database, communication

I am making a voice assistant in python which will take command from an Android app which will convert the users voice command to text but I am not getting any way to send that text to dekstop application

First I thought of firebase but firebase do not support dekstop application ...

Can anyone help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am also finding solution similar like your use case. must post your solution whenever you find any way to do this. i want to make billing software where android can scan barcode and add those entry to PC software